# How to hash SCSS files with Vite?

Tags: typescript, sass, vite

I am using Vite with TypeScript, React and Sass and have an index.html where I just include the index.tsx.

The generated index.html inserts the generated JavaScript files as desired with a hash in the filename. The generated CSS on the other hand (and also .ttf and .svg files) are placed in a src folder (in dist) and do not contain a hash.

This is how I import the .scss in my index.tsx:

```
import './index.scss';
```

Why does the generated CSS file not have a hash, but the JS files do? And why is it placed in a src folder instead of an assets folder like the other files?

I already tried to include the CSS in the index.html, hoping that Vite would then treat them like the JS files and place them in the correct assets folder and a hash in the filename, but that didn't work.

Comment: Please share your Vite config.

Comment: @Arkellys Sure, here you go: https://pastebin.com/uyJifjMW

Comment: Ok I just found out that it is because of the `assetFileNames` option. I thought because the JS files were also named correctly, it would not be because of that. Thanks anyway for the answer!